Polars: "explode" an enum-valued series into two columns of enum index and enum value
import polars as pl

dates = ["2024 Jan", "2024 Feb"]
DateEnum = pl.Enum(dates)

date_table = pl.DataFrame(
    {"date": pl.Series(raw_dates, dtype=DateEnum)}
)
date_table.explode("date") # fails

    {
        "date": pl.Series(raw_dates, dtype=plDateEnum).cast(dtype=str),
        "index": pl.Series(raw_dates, dtype=plDateEnum).cast(dtype=int),
    }
)
date_table # fails

I hoped to see a dataframe like:
from typing import Enum

pyDateEnum = Enum("Dates", raw_dates)
date_table = pl.DataFrame({
  "date": pl.Series("dates", [x.name for x in pyDateEnum], dtype=str),
  "index": pl.Series("indices", [x.value - 1 for x in pyDateEnum], dtype=int)
})
date_table

shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬───────┐
│ date     ┆ index │
│ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ i64   │
╞══════════╪═══════╡
│ 2024 Jan ┆ 0     │
│ 2024 Feb ┆ 1     │
└──────────┴───────┘

How do I go about doing this using Polars, without resorting to Python enums?

i'm not sure if there's more native way to do that but you can always cast:
date_table.with_columns(
    name = pl.col.date.cast(str),
    value = pl.col.date.cast(pl.UInt32)
)

┌──────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ date     ┆ name     ┆ value │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ enum     ┆ str      ┆ u32   │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ 2024 Jan ┆ 2024 Jan ┆ 0     │
│ 2024 Feb ┆ 2024 Feb ┆ 1     │
└──────────┴──────────┴───────┘

